# ASP.NET Core 2.2 - [assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))] doesnt make warnings go away

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

1. Installed the package for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzer`
2. Added `[assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]` to top of my controller namespace
3. still get warnings without individually specifying `ProducesResponseType`

[image]

EDIT: only works if i put it directly on the method, also tried 3.0 preview version of the package, same problem, also tried on a different machine with vs 2017 enterprise and same problem.

Logged a bug with ms [ASP.NET Core 2.2 - [assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))] doesnt make warnings go away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857321/asp-net-core-2-2-assembly-apiconventiontypetypeofdefaultapiconventions)

```
    [ApiConventionMethod(typeof(DefaultApiConventions), nameof(DefaultApiConventions.Get))]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

Comment: Does error go away if you use `ProducesResponseType` on controller method?

Comment: Yes they do, but the point of doing a global `[assembly: ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]` suppose to make them go away

Comment: Is your project in ASP.NET Core 2.2?

Comment: Yes it is a asp.net 2.2 core

Comment: Try `[assembly: ApiController]` on `Startup` class namespace and let me know please!

Comment: did not change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185510/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-zoinky).

Comment: What is your VS version? I made a test with VS Version 15.9.3, Asp.net Core Template 2.2 and package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Api.Analyzers` with version `2.2.0`, it works correctly. Make a test with [MVC2_2](https://github.com/Edward-Zhou/AspNetCore/tree/master/MVC/MVC2_2) to check whether it is related with your environment.

Comment: I tried both in vs2017 pro 15.9.4 and vs20017 ent 15.9.4 and same issues, after trying your sample out, i was not getting errors in that, so i created a default MVC project (not API) added the packaing and I was NOT having the issue.

It seems the problem has to do with actually dong a pure web api 2.2 core project. 

You can try that and you will have the same problem I assume
1. Started a default web api project 2. add the package, 3. add the assembly import, 4.  Have one of your controller methods to return "BadRequest" and you should see what I am seeing